# Can I use HTML as front end with Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc

```
I want to build an application using Spring MVC with front end as HTML, CSS and Jquery.
```

I want to know if this is possible. Spring MVC has Model object that can be accessed in the UI to access the server side data.

I have following in my controller

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
}
```

My HTML code will be as follows

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
  <body>

   <c:out value="${msg}"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

http://spring.io/guides - has all the information on individual Spring projects and indepth Tutorials.

You can also leverage other template engines such as Velocity and Thymeleaf to have better and more fluid HTML5 pages.

personally i use Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org/
Spring 3 MVC + Thymeleaf tutorials - http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html

Comment: If your question has been answered please mark it as so :)